# Exception while reading text file in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, rdd

I read a text file using spark and saved it in JavaRDD ,and trying to print the data saved in RDD.I am running my code in a cluster with a master and two slaves.But I am getting exception ,such as, **containers exceeds thresholds** ,while iterating through the RDD. The code was running perfectly in standalone mode.

My Code:

```
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext("spark://master.com:7077","Spark-Phoenix");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);

JavaRDD<String> trs_testing = jsc.textFile("hdfs://master.com:9000/Table/sample");


//using iterator
Iterator<String> iStr= trs_testing.toLocalIterator();

while(iStr.hasNext()){ //here I am getting exception    
    System.out.println("itr next : " + iStr.next());        
}   

//using foreach()
trs_testing.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {//here I am getting exception
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override public void call(String line) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(line);       
        }           
});

//using collect()
for(String line:trs_testing.collect()){//here I am getting exception 
    System.out.println(line);
}

//using foreachPartition()
trs_testing.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {//here I am getting exception 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override public void call(Iterator<String> arg0) throws Exception {          
            while (arg0.hasNext()) {            
                String line = arg0.next();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
    }
});
```

Exception:

> ERROR ***TaskSchedulerImpl Lost executor 0 on master.com: Remote RPC
>   client disassociated***. Likely due to ***containers exceeding thresholds,***
>   or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages. ERROR
>   TaskSchedulerImpl Lost executor 1 on slave1.com: Remote RPC client
>   disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or
>   network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages. ERROR
>   TaskSchedulerImpl Lost executor 2 on master.com: Remote RPC client
>   disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or
>   network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages. ERROR
>   TaskSchedulerImpl Lost executor 3 on slave2.com: Remote RPC client
>   disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or
>   network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages. ERROR
>   TaskSetManager Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job
>   aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most
>   recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, slave1.com):
>   ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running
>   tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to
>   containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs
>   for WARN messages. Driver stacktrace:     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1324)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1298)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1338)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1337)    at
>   com.test.java.InsertE.main(InsertE.java:147)

Answer (score 0):

When you are running the Spark Job in local system/standalone mode, all the data will be in the same machine, hence you'll be able to iterate and print the data.

When the Spark Job is run on cluster mode/environment, the data will be split in to fragments and distributed to all the machines in the cluster(RDD - Resilient Distributed Datasets). Hence, to print in this manner, you'll have to use, a ***foreach()*** function.

**Try this:**

```
trs_testing.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>(){ 
          public void call(String line) {
              System.out.println(line);
          }
});
```

Comment: I tried foreach(),foreachpartition() and collect() too.But still facing the same issue.The moment I am trying to process the data ,it is throwing exception.Can you suggest any other alternative to read the data?

Comment: The code seem to be fine. Can you also provide the command you used to run the spark job? The configurations of the worker and master nodes. The size of data you are trying to load from hdfs too?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.I was executing the code through my machine whereas my master and slaves were running on a remote server.I exported my code to the remote server and was finally able to process the data.